# C# process.start parameters

Tags: c#, parameters, process.start

We can create a shortcut to an `.exe` file.

As you know, shortcut files can contain *parameters*.

I want to build a program that automatically assigns parameters using `C #` code.

Here is my code:

```
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpWebRequest req =
        WebRequest.Create("http://test.com/contact_ip.txt") as HttpWebRequest;

        HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string ResponseText = sr.ReadToEnd();
            //ResponseText

            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(".\\folder\\test.exe");
            // e.g.)) test.exe 127.0.0.1(ResponseText) 1234(port)
        }
    }
```

How do I include the IP address and port at `test.exe`?

```
e.g.)) .\folder\test.exe 127.0.0.1 4455

e.g.2)) Var ResponseText = ip Address
```

Comment: You can use [this static overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx) instead which accepts `arguments` as the second parameter.

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpWebRequest req =
    WebRequest.Create("http://test.com/contact_ip.txt") as HttpWebRequest;

    HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string ResponseText = sr.ReadToEnd();
        //ResponseText

        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = @".\\folder\\test.exe";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "127.0.0.1 4455";
        proc.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: well this is certainly the way to do it. What is text.exe? are you sure that it is managing the arguments you are sending?

Comment: new System.Diagnostics.Process(".\\folder\\test.exe");
There is a red underline in the above sentence.

Warning messages are not displayed in English, so I will translate them arbitrarily :

There is no constructor that takes one argument to 'System.Diagnostics.Process'.

Comment: Test.exe is a client program that can change the connection server by taking ip address and port as arguments.

Comment: Wow, it works really well. 
C # functions are difficult to apply because of many kinds. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: thanks. glad it helped. Dont forget to mark as answer :D